# How to compute seconds in a date range, only counting certain hours and/or days?

Tags: python, datetime, rrule

I need to calculate the exact seconds an event is active for, between 2 dates. However, the event can have additional constraints - it may only be active in certain time slots and/or days of the week.

I tried using rrule with frequency `rrule.SECONDLY`, but the function takes 2-3 seconds to run - and this computation needs to run extremely quickly, ~3 ms. I used `rrule.HOURLY` and multiplied by 3600.

I implemented a system as shown below, but it has the drawback that it doesn't count the 28 minutes after 16:00 hour of the end date and 10 mins in 16:00 hour of start date in the example.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import rrule

time_slot = {'start': "173000", 'end': "180000"}
start_date = datetime(2015, 3, 5, 16, 50)
end_date = datetime(2015, 3, 27, 16, 28)

start_hour = int(time_slot.get('start', '000000')[0:2])
end_hour = int(time_slot.get('end', '235959')[0:2])
start_minute = int(time_slot.get('start', '000000')[2:4])
end_minute = int(time_slot.get('end', '235959')[2:4])
time_slot_hours = []
time_slot_minutes = []

if start_minute:
    time_slot_minutes.append({'hour': start_hour, 'minutes': [m for m in range(start_minute, 60)]})
    start_hour += 1

if end_minute:
    time_slot_minutes.append({'hour': end_hour, 'minutes': [m for m in range(0, end_minute)]})

for hour in range(start_hour, end_hour):
    time_slot_hours.append(hour)

active_seconds = 60 * 60 * len(list(rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, byhour=time_slot_hours, dtstart=start, until=end)))
for m in time_slot_minutes:
    active_seconds += 60 * len(list(rrule.rrule(rrule.MINUTELY, byminute=m['minutes'], byhour=m['hour'], dtstart=start, until=end)))
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: The library does some pretty extensive caching, which may help with your slowness problem if you enable it. https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/rrule.py#L259